# Execute multiple queries in java using MySQL JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, sql

My objective is to be able to run Descriptive Statistics mySQL queries on my tables on Java. Some of these queries consist of several parts to get one result such as getting a median of a column which is comprised as follows:

```
set @ct := (select count(1) from employee);
set @row_id := 0;

select avg(VacationHours) as median
from (select * from employee order by VacationHours) AS T
where (select @row_id := @row_id + 1) 
between @ct/2.0 and @ct/2.0 + 1;
```

Basically I want to run that query all at once which technically consists of 3 parts. So far all the questions regarding running multiple queries at once consisted of either just SELECT or UPDATE which isn't exactly describing my situation. I have tried adding `?allowMultiQueries=true` to the end of my dbURL to no avail.

The code I am using right to execute the above SQL is by using

```
 pStmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
 rs = pStmt.executeQuery(sql);
```

which is giving me the error
java.sql.SQLException: ResultSet is from UPDATE. No Data.

Any help would be much appreciated :)

Comment: Why can't you store value of (select count(1) from employee) in java variable. First execute above query, assign it to java var then use var in query statement which dynamically generate your sql statement. No need to use set @. Your @row_id usage is not clear, explain what you are doing with @row_id?

Comment: please refer this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/19673296/2068790

Comment: To be honest I have no idea, I had found the code to this query in [this link](https://www.periscopedata.com/blog/medians-in-sql.html)

Comment: Can you use other libraries than Java's standard library?